# How to install external fonts into android studio for low target versions?

Tags: android, fonts

I was looking for some client approved fonts for my android application. but the problem is how can i make my android application supportable for external fonts.
Because in the assets/fonts folder the files seem to be invalid with ? sign in them.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the extension of the fonts? How is it invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your file TTF files in `Assets/fonts` .then

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox);
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

here is very good tutorial on this click [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, you can use this library:
[Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

So you can still use your fonts from the assets/fonts folder, then use the dependency for injecting the font in the layouts you want to use your custom font.

See the [read me](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/blob/master/README.md) for more info and sample for implementing it.

For the font extension, I think Android supports `.ttf` fonts.